# how to store the array into $localStorage?

Tags: angularjs, ng-storage

I am storing two values into an array. They are age and name. How do I use $localStorage to store this array? When I refresh the page, both the array and $localStorage are null.

```
var app=angular.module("plunker",["ngStorage"]);
app.controller("xCtrl",function($scope,$rootScope,$localStorage){
   $scope.list=[]
   $scope.x={}
   $scope.add=function(x){
   $scope.list.push(x);
   $localStorage.list= $scope.list;
   $scope.$storage= $localStorage.list
   $scope.x={}
}
})
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/6vGduA4hWzcuYhA1fwHC?p=preview

Comment: it's not clear what your question is, but it *seems* like you are asking how to retrieve items from `$localStorage` on page load, since your `add` method looks fine.

Comment: when refreshing the page $localStorage become null and table also null. check my plunker. when i add some values into table those value are not constant.

Comment: put a if condition if $localStorage is defined or not. If it is defined don't push it again.
this way on reload if your localStorage having any value It will remain there.

Comment: please add the code in plunker...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be your controller code

```
$scope.list=[]
   $scope.x={}
   if($localStorage.list){
     $scope.$storage=$localStorage.list;
     $scope.list=$localStorage.list;
   }
   $scope.add=function(x){
    $scope.list.push(x);
    $scope.$storage= $localStorage.list
    $scope.x={}
  }
```